# saveenv fails after U-Boot update - Writing to NAND... FAILED

Tags: embedded, arm, environment-variables, block, u-boot

to be able to run my eSata Sheevaplug with Debian Wheezy I had to upgrade U-Boot to the DENX version. 
As step-by-step guide I used [this read from Martin Michlmayr](http://www.cyrius.com/debian/kirkwood/sheevaplug/uboot-upgrade/). I did the upgrade using screen and a USB stick at the plug.
The upgrade went good and after resetting I got the plug started with the new version.

```
Marvell>> version
U-Boot 2013.10 (Oct 21 2013 - 21:06:56)
Marvell-Sheevaplug - eSATA - SD/MMC
gcc (Debian 4.8.1-9) 4.8.1
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.23.52.20130727
Marvell>>
```

In the guide is written to set machid environment variable and MAC address.
But unfortunatly saveenv fails due to bad blocks in the NAND. I tried different versions of U-Boot also [the one provided by NewIT](http://www.downloadsnewit.co.uk/u-boot/recovery/sheevaplug/denx/u-boot.kwb). All behave the same way.

```
Marvell>> setenv machid a76
Marvell>> saveenv
Saving Environment to NAND...
Erasing NAND...
Skipping bad block at  0x00060000                                          

Writing to NAND... FAILED!
```

There are some blocks marked as bad, which might be normal - by NewIT.

```
Marvell>> nand info

Device 0: nand0, sector size 128 KiB
  Page size      2048 b
  OOB size         64 b
  Erase size   131072 b
Marvell>> nand bad

Device 0 bad blocks:
  00060000
  00120000
  00360000
  039c0000
  0c300000
  10dc0000
  1ac40000
  1f1c0000
```

Has someone a clue what the problem is and what I need to change to be able saving environment variables in u-boot?

Thanks,
schibbl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to configuration of environment variable storage at NAND, the sector size of 128k and a bad block mapping the environment variable storage adress it is not possible to write env to NAND.

```
Marvell>> nand bad

Device 0 bad blocks:
  00060000
  ...
```

[include/configs/sheevaplug.h](http://git.denx.de/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=u-boot/u-boot-marvell.git;a=blob;f=include/configs/sheevaplug.h;hb=HEAD) which points perfectly to the bad block.

```
/*
 * max 4k env size is enough, but in case of nand
 * it has to be rounded to sector size
 */
#define CONFIG_ENV_SIZE                 0x20000 /* 128k */
#define CONFIG_ENV_ADDR                 0x60000
#define CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET               0x60000 /* env starts here */
```

Because of unused sector 0x80000 to 0x9FFFF I moved env storage there.

```
/*
 * max 4k env size is enough, but in case of nand
 * it has to be rounded to sector size
 */
#define CONFIG_ENV_SIZE                 0x20000 /* 128k */
#define CONFIG_ENV_ADDR                 0x80000
#define CONFIG_ENV_OFFSET               0x80000 /* env starts here due to bad block */
```

Beware! We have to ensure our compiled u-boot.kwb is less then 384k. Otherwise we will write u-boot to bad block marked memory and will brick the device.

Best way to recompile with custom env address, is to use [Michlmayrs sources](http://people.debian.org/~tbm/u-boot/2013.10-2/), which includes patches for mmc and e-sata support.